# Достать содержимое не html-iframe

Tags: html, javascript, iframe

```
function ifrl() {
var text = document.getElementById('ifr').document.innerHTML;
alert(text);
}
-------------------------------------------------------
<iframe onload="ifrl()" id="ifr"
" style="display:none;" src="http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.1/MTL/chartdata;type=close;range=1d/json/"></iframe>
```

innerHTML  в моём примере не сработал. Что использовать вместо?

p.s. формат содержимого iframe - json

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/questions/212505#212612 посмотри мой комментарий на ответ. Скажу сразу - работать с iframe можно только на том домене, где находится родитель.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужно кроссдоменно получить `json`, стоит подключать его как скрипт (`<script src=""></script>`). Именно в вашем примере стоит предварительно создать функцию `finance_charts_json_callback`, которая будет обрабатывать `json`-ответ как аргумент.

Comment: Можно поподробнее? Так сходу и не въедишь в курс дела :)

Comment: Обратите внимание на [адрес](http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.1/MTL/chartdata;type=close;range=1d/json/), который вы обратываете. Там идёт не "чистый" `json`-ответ, а вызов функции с ним внутри:

    finance_charts_json_callback({/*json*/})

Следовательно, если подключить этот файл как скрипт, тоесть:

    <script src="http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.1/MTL/chartdata;type=close;range=1d/json/"></script>

То выполнится код внутри, тоесть вызовется та самая функция с обьектом внутри.

Comment: Чтобы обработать её, предварительно нужно написать скрипт, где обьявляется функция с таким же названием. Тоесть условно так:

    function finance_charts_json_callback(obj){
        return obj;//json
    }

Comment: @Crasher А что передаётся под obj?